# Remote UI Automation Project White

Tags: wcf, ui-automation

I have a Win32 application that I am trying UI automate.

I have written a .Net winforms client which uses 'Project White' UI automation to automate the Win32 application.

When I click the buttons in the .Net client GUI everything works fine, it operates the Win32 application as expected.

I want run the automation remotely so I added a WCF basicHttpBinding interface to the .Net winform client.

When I call the same functions from WCF the .Net client locks up until the WCF request times out, then the automation starts working correctly.

I can't work out if it's a threading issue or a permissions issue.  The Win32 application launches from WCF it's just when you try and start operating it the app locks up.

Any advice would be gratefully received.

Answer (score -1):

Based on this [blog post,](http://lozanotek.com/blog/archive/2007/04/02/19961.aspx) you may be having a thread model problem. Just reading what is in that post though would make me very leery of trying what you're doing... Good luck!